# Fade out animation when ng-if = false

Tags: html, css, angularjs

Is there any way to animate with fade out when `ng-if="false"` instead of instantly hide the HTML element?

I can fade-in when `ng-if="true"` but can't when `ng-if="false"`. When `ng-if="true"` I'm using [Animate.css](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) library to animate with fade-in.

Comment: Use ngShow instead. If uses the same logic as ngIf, but applies a CSS class with `display: hidden !important;` instead of actually removing the element.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You should use `ng-animate` for this. It's a native angular library that adds transition classes and a delay upon removing elements

```js
angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate']).
controller('ctrl', function(){});
```

```css
.fade-element-in.ng-enter {
  transition: 0.8s linear all;
  opacity: 0;
}

.fade-element-in-init .fade-element-in.ng-enter {
  opacity: 1;
}

.fade-element-in.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.fade-element-in.ng-leave {
  transition: 0.3s linear all;
  opacity: 1;
}
.fade-element-in.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.0/angular-animate.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <a href="" ng-click="showMe = !showMe">Click me</a>
  <div class="fade-element-in" ng-if="showMe">
    SomeContent
  </div>
  <div class="fade-element-in" ng-if="!showMe">
    SomeOtherContent
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How would you do this with the angular animations library in the newer version 4.x.x