# Angular ng-show with fade expression does not remove the div

Tags: javascript, angularjs, fade, ng-show

I am trying to display a div with an error message with ng-show along with ng-class set as fade with an expression. The message fades away after the set time, however, the div created to display the error message does not get removed.

I would like the created div to be removed as well when the message fades. Could someone please help?

Here is my codepen - [link](https://codepen.io/nirajupadhyay11/pen/WydVOO)

Here is my code for the html

```
  <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" 
type="text/css" />    
    <section data-ng-app="app" class="container" data-ng-controller="messageController">    

        <hr />      

      <div data-ng-show="showError" ng-class="{fade:doFade}" class="alert alert-danger"><strong>Error:</strong> {{errorMessage}}</div>

      <button data-ng-click="fakeError()" class="btn btn-default">Fake an Error</button>
      <hr />      
    </section>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>
```

and the JS code

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.controller('messageController', ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout){

  $scope.showError = false;
  $scope.doFade = false;

  $scope.fakeError = function(){

    //reset
    $scope.showError = false;
    $scope.doFade = false;

    $scope.showError = true;

    $scope.errorMessage = 'We\'re mixing apples and oranges!';

    $timeout(function(){
      $scope.doFade = true;
    }, 2500);
  };
}]);
```

Comment: Seems like your CSS is relevant.

Comment: Try using ng-if, hopefully, this post will give you an idea
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34936333/fade-out-animation-when-ng-if-false

Comment: Hi, thank you for looking into this. I changed ng-show to ng-if but the div still does not get removed. Here is my codepen - codepen.io/nirajupadhyay11/pen/WydVOO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-show` sets only style display conditionaly, soyour div will be always present in the page, only not visible if condition is falsy.

Use `ng-if` instead to conditionaly add/remove element.

Easiest way to animate ng-if is to use [angular-animate](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate) library. Using this lib you will get control over rendering stages of various directives.
These stages are marked via specific css classes, which you can target and style 
 transitions of element.

For *ng-if* directive, there are available classes *.ng-enter*, *.ng-leave*, *.ng-enter-active*, *.ng-leave-active*

Via these classes you can define desired transition, in your case it is fade.

Example of fading on remove:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NzyqvL

Comment: Hi, thank you for looking into this. I changed ng-show to ng-if but the div still does not get removed. Here is my codepen - https://codepen.io/nirajupadhyay11/pen/WydVOO

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Thank you so much. This is really helpful